# POS Tagging output is different for the stanford parser and the stanford corenlp online versions?

Tags: pos-tagger, stanford-nlp

Is the model files being used by the parser(http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp) and corenlp(http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process) are different? Or is there a corenlp version difference at the back end?

Input Text: "I want Hand Wash."

From parser: (ROOT (S (NP (PRP I))  (VP (VBP want) **(NP (NNP Hand)** (NNP Wash.)))   (. .)))

From corenlp: (ROOT (S (NP (PRP I))  (VP (VBP want) **(VP (VB Hand)**  (NP (NNP Wash.)))) (. .)))

I have tried the stanford api calls also but the output resembles the corenlp version, so I want to find the api call which can give me the output similar to the parser version above as that is the corect one.